# How do I make a form field not neccessray for validation in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

I have 2 forms:  `$patientForm` and `$investigationForm`.

They are both combined into one view, so the user fills in the fields and 2 records are created in Patient table and Investigation table.  Investigation table has a foreign key - to the patient name.  So one patient can have many investigations.

So I obviously need the patient id to add it to an investigation record as a foreign key.  However, the patient id isn't created until the patient form is saved.

So I have devised the following function:

```
protected function processPatientInvestigation(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $investigationForm, sfForm $patientForm)
{
    $patientForm->bind($request->getParameter($patientForm->getName()), $request->getFiles($patientForm->getName()));

    if ($patientForm->isValid() && $investigationForm->isValid() ) {        
        $patientForm->save();       
        $values = $request->getParameter($investigationForm->getName());
        $values['patient_id'] = $patientForm->getObject()->getId();
        $investigationForm->bind($values, $request->getFiles($investigationForm->getName()));
        $investigationForm->save();     
    }
```

The if statement always fails because `$investigationForm` isn't valid until I give its form field a `patient_id` value.  So this value is empty at this point.  However, if I just took the `isValid()` check out for `$investigation` form and put it down later on after the `$patientForm` is saved. This means that if it failed validation and the user had missed a field, when they don't click submit again, the whole function would run again meaning we'd have duplicate patient records.

So what I think the answer is, is making the patient_id field not be validated, so it can be empty and still pass the `isValid()` function.

Please let me know if this isn't clear.  Hope you can advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following though this should really be done in the forms configure method.

```
$patientForm->getValidator('patient_id')->addOption('required', false);
```

Comment: I did end up putting this in the form class.

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner solution would be to set all your validation rules in the **/lib/form/*Form.class.php** file itself (rather than manipulating it in your action).

```
$this->validatorSchema['patient_id'] = new sf*Validator(array(
  'required' => false
), array());
```

If you just want to let a form field completely unvalidated, use

```
$this->validatorSchema['patient_id'] = sfValidatorPass()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with embedded forms and let symfony handle the saving correctly.

Comment: I know, I think I should have done that, but I went about it this way, and don't have a lot of time to look into how to do embedded forms now.